# Count set bits in python does not work for large numbers

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

```
import math


rem =  input()

def onecount(rem):
    count = 0 #counts the number of one bits
    while rem != 0 :
        highestindex = math.floor(math.log(rem,2))
        rem = rem - math.pow(2,highestindex)
        count += 1
    return count

print onecount(rem)
#the above program takes O(log n) ... excluding the time taken by math.log and math.pow
#the above program seems to give wrong results for extremely large numbers. Why????




#another program to do the same job
def onecount2(rem):
    count = 0
    while rem : 
        count += rem & 1
        rem >>= 1

    return count

print onecount2(rem)
```

I have written two types of functions to calculate the set bits in an integer in python. The second function works well for all the integers (small and large). The first function works correctly for integers around 10^7 but fails for numbers larger than that. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: math.pow returns a float so "rem" becomes a float and float arithmetic is inexact. Testing for exactly zero may fail.

Answer (score 0):

The functions in `math` (or most of them?) are operating on floats rather than ints. Ints in python are not limited in size, but floats have the usual limits.

You can verify this with:

```
In [11]: type(2**100 - math.pow(2,99))                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[11]: float

In [12]: type(2**100)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[12]: int
```

In practice this means your answers from `math` functions, and the results of calculations in `onecount` will not be precise over the range you can represent in float.

Comment: Got it @viraptor . Thanks for the explanation! It works when I am using int(math.pow()) .

Comment: @Ashmil don't rely on `int(math.pow())` - it will work until it doesn't. For example `math.pow(2, 1024)` raises `OverflowError`, but `2**1024` still works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first function uses `float`s instead of `int`s and the error builds up.

`math.floor(math.log())` will return an int so that part is fine. However, `math.pow` returns a float – making `rem = rem - math.pow()` use floating-point math instead of integer math.

Since this occurs in a loop, each iteration has the potential to make `rem` slightly more inaccurate. With large numbers, there will be more iterations of the loop and therefore more error built up by the end. Additionally, floats get less accurate further from 0 (i.e. very large positive/negative numbers), so that may have some impact as well.

Both of these together means that `rem - math.pow(2, highest index)` takes an inaccurate float value for `rem` and then subtracts an inaccurate `math.pow(2, highest index)` value from it. Repeating this step in a loop just compounds the problem, introducing more error at each iteration.

A simple adjustment of `int(math.pow(2, highest index))` should correct it:

```
def onecount(rem):
    count = 0 #counts the number of one bits
    while rem != 0 :
        highestindex = math.floor(math.log(rem,2))
        rem = rem - int(math.pow(2,highestindex))
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at my question and trying to answer it. But I have a question here. Math.pow() in the code I have written will always give an integer and never a float because the base and power are both integers (base 2 and power - highestindex - is coverted into int in the previous line). However, your idea of using int() works because of different reasons. Please refer to answer by @viraptor . Thanks for you attempt. I really appreciate it!

Comment: `math.pow()` will actually still return a float. Even though the parameters are both integers, so mathematically you could know the result is an integer, it's not implemented that way here. The docs specify this as a difference between `math.pow()` and the `**` operator that @viraptor suggests. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.pow. In this way `**` and `int()` should have the same effect, although `**` is potentially more accurate – that seems like the way to go.